# Adding Liquidity to Uniswap fails

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

I'm trying to add liquidity to my smart contract on Uniswap, however whenever I try to add liquidity, I can approve the transaction, but hitting apply does nothing. The Javascript console shows an error saying: not able to predict gas gee. There's also a problem with TransferFrom.

```
 function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
        //burn&tax
        burn(msg.sender,burnTaxFee(value));
        sendDev(msg.sender,devTaxFee(value));

        balances[to] += value; //send the value - burnt tokens to reciever
        balances[msg.sender] -= value ; //subtract value sent from sender.
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(from) >= value, 'balance too low');
        require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, 'allowance too low');
        
        //burn&tax
        burn(msg.sender,burnTaxFee(value));
        sendDev(msg.sender,devTaxFee(value));
    
        balances[to] += value; //send the value - burnt tokens to reciever
        balances[from] -= value; //subtract value sent from sender.
        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;   
    }
```

I'm thinking it might have to do with my smart contract? for each transfer, I also do 2 separate transfers that go into two separate wallets. Do multiple transfers triggered by the normal transfer function cause problems with uniswap?

```
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={"code":-32603,"message":"execution reverted: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED","data":{"originalError":{"code":3,"data":"0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000245472616e7366657248656c7065723a205452414e534645525f46524f4d5f4641494c454400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","message":"execution reverted: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED"}}}, method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0xA6486944b1119CDAB743694873e28ad8eF3f89e2","to":"0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x1717b72f0a4000"},"data":"0xf305d71900000000000000000000000054620e1c1c39d689fc73214bb1de16f743214dce0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000113d788ba2b887b6c80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000113d788ba2b887b6c8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001717b72f0a4000000000000000000000000000a6486944b1119cdab743694873e28ad8ef3f89e20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060c1817e","accessList":null}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.2.0)
```

Another idea I had was that I'm not using the SafeMath library, would non-safemath equations cause issues with Uniswap?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the contract source code, as well as the exact error messages. Currently it's not possible to reproduce and troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Have you figured it out? I have the same issue with adding initial liquidity.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are deploying your own token with either fees or burns, its probably that the uniswap router is not treating your token as a token with fees. The uniswap router has specific seperate functions for swapping when tokens have fees or burns on transfer. Its likely the ui of uniswap does not know to call these functions since you deployed this token yourself.

So you can either make your own UI to support swapping your token with the correct function call to the router, or figure out how to integrate your token with fees into uniswap. I'm not totally sure how to do that off the top of my head, but I hope this helps you at least identify the source of your problem.